# Interactive Text-Adventure

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create an interactive text based game for my first HTML/Javascript project. It would be similar to Zork, specifically in regards to how it reacts to user input and goes through the adventure based on decisions the user has typed in.

I've created basic HTML and CSS code to start the storyline, but now need help creating the code for the HTML and Javascript functions that would read the user input and return the appropriate response, such as "You went north. You see..." or "The monster attacks you." etc etc.

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, just hoping someone can give me an example of the format I need to put in both the HTML and Javascript files I can look to when I write out all of the functions for the code.

Base HTML code currently:

Welcome, brave adventurer.  
  What is your name?

**This area would have a text input, and based upon response the following line would log the following text plus the name input by the user**

Pleased to meet you,  
  Test line text.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected input from the clients and the responses to those inputs, how you plan to deal with them and maybe give a visual of what you are working with? Also please include any relevant source code. Thank you.

Comment: "I'm not looking for someone to write code for me" = I'm looking for someone to write code for me.

Comment: If you can give some detail of how you want to run the story deal with the actions/clients input then it will be easier to assist you. I haven't ever attempted to write a text adventure before but I liked the idea of it and not really 100% sure how you want to approach it but here is a little something I have written [**Text Adventure Demo**](https://coded4u.com/Text-Adventure/)

Comment: NewToJS: So what would be expected would be something along these lines: "You are in a dimly lit cave. The light seems to be coming from a tunnel that emerges on the opposite side of the cave. There also appears to be noise coming from somewhere in the tunnel." "What do you do?"

Then based off the users input, for example, "Examine cave" or "Enter tunnel", which would load another string of text, either describing the cave or proceeding into the tunnel.

I will edit the code to show the barebones HTML I have, I have not started the JS.

Comment: ecg8: Incorrect.

Comment: NewToJS: Looking at your Text Adventure Demo, the format would be similar, just without the graphic background and "cheat sheet" option, as I want to allow for more creative input (within a certain extent of course), and additions like hit points, mana, etc.

Comment: @Blazika The adventure story isn't going to be fantastic since that is a demo/example and the cheat sheet is there only so you can find the expected answer to move forward while testing the demo. If that is something you'd be interested in then you can always modify the source code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a very similar project in python, so I can use my project as an example for you. With the intention of creating other text adventures in the future, I made a text adventure engine for myself. Here are its basic capabilities, which in my opinion are important to have in many text adventures.

1. First, you need to make a text parser function to parse out the words in the user's input, so you can begin to comprehend what commands they are using. If you don't quite know how to do this, I'm sure that there are plenty of online resources on the topic
2. You need to come up with a set of specific commands the user can use (ie go north, use , give, etc.)
3. For your own convenience as the game designer, you should use object-oriented coding. I created a class for every type of object you would need (for example person, location, weapon, etc.) in the text adventure. That way I could easily create these things which are essential to all text adventures.

This is just a place to start. Let me know if you have any other questions. Hope this was helpful (I'm new to this website so don't really know how to answer stuff).